# VB.NET Linq to Entities Query with child objects

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities, parent-child

Basically I have the follwing:

```
Dim ctx As New AdminCoreEntities
Dim roles = (From r In ctx.Roles where r.Name.StartsWith("cust") Select r) 'list of System.Linq.IQueryable(Of AdminCoreModel.Role)

 Dim items = From i In ctx.QuickLinks.Include("Roles")
             Where (i.TenantID = "470556ba-3574-4b01-a619-b85e9721b966" AndAlso i.Roles.Contains(roles))
             Select New With {
                               i.ID,
                               i.Name,
                               .Roles = (From r In i.Roles Select New With {.Id = r.ID, .Name = r.Name})
                              }
```

The error i get when i run this is:

Unable to cast object of type System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[AdminCoreModel.Role] to type AdminCoreModel.Role

Basically I have a many to many situation and I try to get all the Quicklinks objects queried by their roles
and not quite sure why EF will cast to a single AdminCoreModel.Role when i.Roles is a collections of objects.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `.Contains()` expects one `Role`, and you're passing it a list. That's what the error says.

Try (apologies in advance if I mangle the VB.NET syntax; I don't usually write VB.NET):

```
Dim ctx As New AdminCoreEntities
Dim items = From i In ctx.QuickLinks  ' You don't need Include because you're projecting.
            Where (i.TenantID = "470556ba-3574-4b01-a619-b85e9721b966" 
                   AndAlso i.Roles.Any(Function(role) role.Name.StartsWith("cust"))
            Select New With {
                                i.ID,
                                i.Name,
                                 .Roles = (From r In i.Roles Select New With {.Id = r.ID, .Name = r.Name})
                          }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it, I used: AndAlso i.Roles.Any(Function(role) roles.Contains(role.ID)), the original roles.StartsWith was just for example here an I really needed to query against a collection of roleIds: the originalcollection is  Dim roles = (From r In ctx.Roles Where rolesIds.Contains(r.ID) Select r.ID).ToList()